# How to make a simple bluetooth connection on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, serial, bluetooth

So a week ago I finally got the bluetooth part of my code running. Everything was fine but after some changes and a failed upgrade (bad internet connection) I decided to start a fresh installation using Noobs.

After the upgrade to a newer version of Raspbian I noticed that now the "bluez-utils" were not present on the repositories and a thing about being replaced by the "bluez" package. After some search I found out that "bluez" replace "bluez-utils" with "bluetoothctl".

What are the right packets to install from all of this?

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev libudev-dev libusb-dev bluetooth bluez bluez-firmware --fix-missing
```